# How to make a permanent session on DialogFlow?

Tags: javascript, node.js, dialogflow-es, chatbot, dialogflow-es-fulfillment

**I imagine that to do this I need, somehow, to save the contexts in a DB and return them when requested. In another topic here on Stackoverflow, I found this code below, but when implementing it an error is returned.**

```js
// request to dialogflow detect intent
const request = {
      session: session,
      queryInput: {
                  input
      },
      context:"last received context from dialogflow" //recent context from db
    }; 
    detectIntent(request).then(response=>{
    const context = response.context; //response context
    db.save(context); // save this in db
    return response;
});
```

Comment: What do you mean by making a session permanent? Also what is the error that you encounter using that code? Can you please edit your question and include the error encountered.

Answer (score 0):

dialogflow won't call intents unless the input context is present. no matter how high a priority i give to an intent, if there is a missing context, it won't be invoked. How to resolve this ?